# Can we use Case Comment(internal comments) field while uploading case using data loader

Tags: data-loader

I'm trying to upload close cases using data loader.while mapping fields i can't see case comment(internal comment) field.i have checked field level security & field level visibility its fine.but still can't able to use that field.

is there any way to use that field?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Internal Comments is not really a field even if it looks like one and that is why you will not be able to map it when selecting Case as the target object, the information entered there is actually stored in the CaseComment object.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to this users problem is to update the cases, and then use the success file to insert case comments (using dataloader again), mapping the CaseId Column to the ParentId field.
It might take twice as long but very easy.